# GWT DisclosurePanel()

Tags: java, gwt

Hi i am trying to use DisclosurePanel().

I have 2 `DisclosurePanel`(). when i open the first `DisclosurePanel`(), 2nd `DisclosurePanel`() moves from the original place and start from the end of the size of first `DisclosurePanel`().

What i want to do is

1st DisclosurePanel() should overlap the 2nd DisclosurePanel().

ex
originaly

```
> Music //1st DisclosurePanel()
> Image  //2nd  DisclosurePanel()
```

**after opening**

```
v Music





> Image
```

**What i want is**

```
v Music // display panel
> Image
```

Comment: Sorry, I must be dumb, but I don't get what you want. You want some kind of vertical tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how DisclosurePanel works out of the box -- but it should be possible to fake it:

```
.panel td:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 400px;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Set that css class on the panel (and modify the width, left and margin-top properties).